# Too many Group By dilutes query results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some assistance on a SQL Query. I hope i titled it correctly as I do not want to mislead anyone.

I am attempting to generate a query which will eventually be placed into a view and be used in the Microsoft Power BI tool that will return a count for a given event in the EVENT field/column, which are:

- 6 – Out of Spec Above
- 7 – Out of Spec Below

…that occurred within a given time frame along with the total number of measurements tested.

I am successful if I only group by Date, Item Code, Plant Code, and Property using the query below.

```
SELECT
       CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101) AS [Date],
       stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1 AS Plant_Code,
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5 as Property,
       SUM(CASE WHEN OC_VDATA.EVENT = 6 THEN 1 WHEN OC_VDATA.EVENT = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Out_of_Spec,
       COUNT(*) AS Total_Measured
FROM
       dbo.OC_VDATA INNER JOIN
              dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX ON dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX 
                    AND dbo.OC_VDATA.DATETIME = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX INNER JOIN
              stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES ON LEFT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
                    AND LEFT(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO

WHERE
       CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101) = '08/21/2019'
       and stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE = '20SL'
       AND dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1 = '1011'
       AND dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5 = 'WEIGHT'
       --(CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102) >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-13, 0))

GROUP BY
       CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101), 
       stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1,
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5
```

First Query Results:

[image: First Query Results]

If I add another grouping level, the EVENT, my Total_Measured column gets diluted. I expected this to happen.

```
SELECT
       CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101) AS [Date],
       stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1 AS Plant_Code,
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5 as Property,
       dbo.OC_VDATA.EVENT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN OC_VDATA.EVENT = 6 THEN 1 WHEN OC_VDATA.EVENT = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Out_of_Spec,
       COUNT(*) AS Total_Measured
FROM
       dbo.OC_VDATA INNER JOIN
              dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX ON dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX 
                    AND dbo.OC_VDATA.DATETIME = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX INNER JOIN
              stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES ON LEFT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
                    AND LEFT(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO

WHERE
       CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101) = '08/21/2019'
       and stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE = '20SL'
       AND dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1 = '1011'
       AND dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5 = 'WEIGHT'
       --(CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102) >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-13, 0))

GROUP BY
       CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101), 
       stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1,
       dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5,
       dbo.OC_VDATA.EVENT
```

Second Query Results:

[image: Second Query Results]

With all that said, what I really want is the results from the second query and merge in the Total_Measured column from the first query.

Results I want:

[image: Results I want]

I thought using a CTE was the answer but that takes a while and eventually generates an error.

```
WITH CTE1 AS 
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101) AS Date, 
        stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
        OC_VDATA.UDL1 AS Plant_Code, 
        OC_VDATA.UDL5 AS Property,  
        --SUM(CASE WHEN OC_VDATA.EVENT = 6 THEN 1 WHEN OC_VDATA.EVENT = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Out_of_Spec, 
        COUNT(OC_VDATA.EVENT) AS Total_Measured

    FROM
        OC_VDATA INNER JOIN
            OC_VDAT_AUX ON OC_VDATA.PARTNO = OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX 
                AND OC_VDATA.DATETIME = OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX INNER JOIN
            stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES ON LEFT(OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
                AND LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO

    WHERE
        (CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102) >= DATEADD(month, - 13, GETDATE()))

    GROUP BY
        CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101), 
        stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
        OC_VDATA.UDL1,
        OC_VDATA.UDL5
),

CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101) AS Date, 
        stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
        OC_VDATA.UDL1 AS Plant_Code, 
        OC_VDATA.UDL5 AS Property, 
        OC_VDATA.EVENT, 
        COUNT(*) AS Out_of_Spec

    FROM
        OC_VDATA INNER JOIN
            OC_VDAT_AUX ON OC_VDATA.PARTNO = OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX 
                AND OC_VDATA.DATETIME = OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX INNER JOIN
            stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES ON LEFT(OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
                AND LEFT(OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO

    WHERE
        (CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102) >= DATEADD(month, - 13, GETDATE()))

    GROUP BY
        CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101), 
        stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, 
        OC_VDATA.UDL1,
        OC_VDATA.UDL5,
        OC_VDATA.EVENT
)

SELECT
    cte1.Date,
    cte1.ITEM_CODE,
    cte1.Plant_Code,
    cte1.PROPERTY,
    EVENT,
    Out_of_Spec,
    Total_Measured
FROM 
    cte1 INNER JOIN cte2 on cte1.Date = cte2.date
        and cte1.ITEM_CODE = cte2.ITEM_CODE
        and cte1.Plant_Code = CTE2.Plant_Code
        and cte1.Property = cte2.Property
```

How to achieve what I want? Does anyone have any tips/tricks? Am I even on the right track? Frustration is starting to set in.

Comment: Window function?  In your 2nd query try `COUNT(*) AS Total_Measured over (partition by CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101), stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1, dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5)`

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @avery_larry where do I insert that in the second query? On the line COUNT(*) AS Total_Measured?

Comment: @EricALionsFan Replace your current `Total_Measured` line.  But what I have is wrong.  Try `COUNT(*) over (partition by CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101), stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1, dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5) AS Total_Measured`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TargetDate varchar(10) = '08/21/2019'
;WITH   PlainList AS    
        (
            SELECT
                    [Date]      =   CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102), 101)
                ,   Item_Code   =   stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE
                ,   Plant_Code  =   dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1
                ,   Property    =   dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5
                ,   [Event]     =   dbo.OC_VDATA.[EVENT]
                ,   Out_of_Spec =   CASE OC_VDATA.[EVENT]
                                         WHEN   6   THEN 1 
                                         WHEN   7   THEN 1 
                                                    ELSE 0 
                                    END

            FROM            dbo.OC_VDATA 
                INNER JOIN  dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX             ON  dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX           =   dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO
                                                        AND dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX         =   dbo.OC_VDATA.[DATETIME]
                INNER JOIN  stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES   ON  stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO   =   LEFT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO        , 12)
                                                        AND stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO   =   LEFT(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX  , 12)

            WHERE   1=1
                    AND stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE = '20SL'
                    AND dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1                   = '1011'
                    AND dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5                   = 'WEIGHT'
        )

SELECT  
        [Date]      
    ,   Item_Code   
    ,   Plant_Code  
    ,   Property    
    ,   [Event]     
    ,   Out_of_Spec     =   SUM(Out_of_Spec)
    ,   Total_Measured  =   SUM(1)

FROM    PlainList   P

GROUP BY
        [Date]             
    ,   Item_Code          
    ,   Plant_Code         
    ,   Property           
    ,   [Event] 

HAVING  [Date]  =   @TargetDate
```